# laravel regex validation not working

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, laravel

I've just started using laravel and I'm working on validating a textarea in one of my forms.

The textarea is for the users bio and so I only want to allow letters, numbers, spaces and the following characters: 
, . ? ; : ' " - () ! / @ $

This is what I have

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
array('bio' => array('regex:[a-zA-Z0-9 ,\.\?;:\'"-\(\)!/@\$]')
    )
);
```

I've been searching and trying a lot to get it to work but I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't know how it works in laravel, but you may need (a) delimiters (b) anchoring from start `^` to finish `$`, and (c) probably a `+` (1 character or _more_...).

Comment: Most of the things you are escaping don't need escaping inside of `[]`. Also `-` specifies a range when it's inside of `[]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
array('Regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-! ,\'\"\/@\.:\(\)]+$/')
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvements ProgramFOX!

Comment: How can I put this regex in the laravel validation rule `^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$`